# Преобразовать значения словаря по заданному алгоритму

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь вида {ключ:[список из двух элементов]}

```
d1 = {1:[10, 5], 2:[40, 8], 3:[144, 12], 4:[55, 11]}
```

как его преобразовать в словарь, где в качестве значения выступает результат деления нулевого элемента списка на первый:

```
d2 = {1:(10/5), 2:(40/8), 3:(144/12), 4:(55/11)}
```

чтобы в итоге получилось:

```
d2 = {1:2, 2:5, 3:12, 4:5}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Элементарно:

```
d2 = {key: value[0]//value[1] for key, value in d1.items()}
```

Результат:

```
{1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 12, 4: 5}
```

Метод `.items()` словаря возвращает итератор, представляющий собой последовательность кортежей `(ключ, значение)`, которые потом распаковываются в соответствующие переменные. Если вывести `list(d1.items())`, то результат будет такой:

```
[(1, [10, 5]), (2, [40, 8]), (3, [144, 12]), (4, [55, 11])]
```

`//` - это целочисленное деление, результат деления будет округляться до целого. Если нужен будет `float` (без округления), то для версии Python 3 нужно поменять деление на "одинарное" (`/`), а для версии Python 2 еще и преобразовать хотя бы один из аргументов в `float`:

```
d2 = {key: float(value[0])/value[1] for key, value in d1.items()}
```

Для Python 3 проще:

```
d2 = {key: value[0]/value[1] for key, value in d1.items()}
```

Результат:

```
{1: 2.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 12.0, 4: 5.0}
```